# MIDI Out on Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, midi, pyserial

I'm using buttons in a scan matrix to output MIDI notes to a MIDI-USB converter connected to MIDI-OX.

For this, I'm using Python to figure out when a button is pressed or released and which button it was. This part of the code works fine.

However, I'm getting a lot of inconsistency with the commands received by MIDI-OX. For communications, I have the UART0_TXD pin of the Pi connected directly to pin 2 of the 5 pole DIN connector used for MIDI and PySerial sending the data. As far as I can see, my code should be generating correct commands and sending them over serial correctly so I'm not sure where to go here for troubleshooting.

The code sending the command is as follows:

```
message=chr(0x90) + chr(0x3D) + chr(0x40)
port.write(message)
```

This results in the following output in MIDI-OX:

```
TIMESTAMP IN PORT STATUS DATA1 DATA2 CHAN NOTE EVENT       
007B971E   1  --     90    68    27    1  G# 8 Note On     
007B971E   1  --     FF    --    --   --  ---  System Reset
```

It can be seen above that MIDI-OX is recieving 68 for data 2 and is outputting the correct note (G#) for this number. If however I change the code to read:

```
message=chr(0x90) + chr(0x3C) + chr(0x40)
port.write(message)
```

MIDI-OX output is:

```
TIMESTAMP IN PORT STATUS DATA1 DATA2 CHAN NOTE EVENT               
007FAC19   1  --     81    00    42    2  C  0 Note Off              
007FAC3A   1  --     FF    --    --   --  ---  System Reset
```

Showing that it is receiving completely different data.

Any ideas on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you send 1 thing and the "G sharp?"  turns on, you send a another thing and the wrong note "C" turns off, seems like a good start, why not just iterate though each of the hex `chr` and map the notes, they might not be in hex sequence? Try: `chr(x90) + chr(0x3D) + chr(0x41)` ... half the battle is just basically snooping around changing one thing, then seeing the results, changing another thing, and see the results ... just that over and over again, until you can figure out why it's not doing what you originally expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, all the data MIDI-OX recieved was wrong and I can't see a pattern. I'm suspecting that I'm doing something wrong with PySerial but I don't know what. Either that or my USB-MIDI interface is defective but I don't have a MIDI instrument to check.

Comment: So if you send the same thing over and over again it changes? Maybe some loose voltage, or wires?

Comment: No, this produces the same output every time. When I say I can't see a pattern, I mean I can't see a consistent error in the data. For example if all the data was half the correct value. Instead every value I send seems to be wrong by a random amount.

Comment: I would start at `x000000` and count to `xFFFFFF`, then I would do that again to see if any thing changed. If nothing changed, then  I would "map" the buttons to the values.

Comment: Pin 2 would be the cable's shield. Anyway, MIDI uses a current loop; see the MIDI electrical specification.

Answer (score 0):

Just starting on a similar project, I am referring to your comment:

> Unfortunately, all the data MIDI-OX recieved was wrong and I can't see a pattern. I'm suspecting that I'm doing something wrong with PySerial but I don't know what.

As far as I understood the MIDI baud rate setting is not so simple for a Raspi, see https://zuzebox.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/raspberry-pi-minipiio-midi-board/

Maybe your setup is slightly off synchronization, therefore produces only "almost" correct, but somewhat erratic MIDI data, and needs baud tweaking to get things correct.